# Yii2 How to use dataprovider with custom and dynamic alias

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

In yii2 I have to use SQL with user-defined dynamic alias.

So as it's dynamic so it's not possible to add as public property in the model.

So following code is not working with following SQL:

```
SELECT `item_id`         AS `Item Id`,
       `on_hand`         AS `On Hand`,
       `initial_on_hand` AS `Amount Produced`,
       `best_by_date`    AS `Best By`,
       `item_name`               AS `Item Name`
FROM   `stock`
```

here is yii2 code:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $query,
]);
```

So whats the possible solution using which I can use yii2 grid with pagination and controls?

Comment: Is there a reason why you absolutely must use these aliases in SQL? From your example it looks like using model's labels would be better solution.

Comment: yes, so its because i have used query builder and here user can add their choice of label for any field

Answer (score 1):

use this solution

```
$query = (new Query()) 
       ->select(
       'stock.item_id as Item Id,
        stock.on_hand as On Han,
        stock.intial_on_hand as Amount Produced,
        stock.best_By_date as Best By ,
        stock.item_name as Item Name
       )
        ->from('notifications as n') ->all()
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

instead of doing this you can just simply create a method called attributeLabels() inside of your model stock if your purpose is getting labels .

```
  public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'item_id' => 'Item Id',
            'on_hand' => 'On Hand',
            'initial_on_hand' => 'Amount Produced`,
            'decaissement_id' => 'Decaissement ID',
            'best_by_date' => 'Approved By',
            'item_name' => 'Item Name',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: no that will not work as a user adding alias on the backend I have to create a grid with that label. so its a dynamic value and not predefined

Comment: well, you were not precise in your question so I give you two possibilities.
the second one should works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely insist on using user input as aliases in your SQL query you can use [`yii\data\SqlDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider) instead of `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider`.

I still believe that doing that is really bad idea because of possible SQL injection. There is no way to use parameters as aliases in SQL query. That means you are letting user directly modify your SQL query.

If you want to have dynamic labels you can do it for example this way.
Let's assume you have some dynamic_label tabel in DB where you store the labels set in backend. The table can look for example like this:

| id | model | field | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stock | item_id | Item ID |
| 2 | Stock | on_hand | On hand |

You also have DynamicLabel model as ActiveRecord model for that table. Then, your model can look for example like this:

```
class Stock extends ActiveRecord
{
    private static ?array $labels = null;

    private static function loadLabels(): void
    {
        if (self::$labels !== null) {
            // Labels are already loaded
            return;
        }
        self::$labels = DynamicLabel::find()
           ->select(['label', 'field']) // we will only need columns label and field
           ->where(['model' => 'Stock']) // select only rows that belong to current model 
           ->indexBy('field') // index result using the value in field column
           ->column(); // get first column of result as array
    }

    public function attributeLabels(): array
    {
        self::loadLabels();
        return self::$labels;
    }

    // ... other definitions in Stock model ...
}
```

The labels are stored in static property to make sure that they are loaded only once during request even if multiple instances of Stock model are used and the `attributeLabels()` method is called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = StockModel::find();
$query->select([
            'stock.item_id as Item Id',
            'stock.on_hand as On Han',
            'stock.intial_on_hand as Amount Produced',
            'stock.best_By_date as Best By',
            'stock.item_name as Item Name'
    ]);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);
```